# Cell reusability of UITableview is creating issue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a comment controller.

[image]

So it has image, name, time and comment text. Every thing is fine until the no of comments hits the scroll point. On scroll the cells are being reused and image of one user shows in imageview of another user something like this.

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens when the routine that is asynchronously loading your images isn't checking to make sure that the image view that requested the image has not been reused for a different image. ( This will happen when you scroll quickly through a table view. The cell will get reused before the image download completes. )

The typical solution is that you use a package like SDWebImage, or you subclass the image view class to have a url property, and you check to make sure that the url on the image view matches the download that just completed before setting the image.

Comment: I am using firebase and if rules of storage are set as only authenticated read than external liberaries cant access the storage i.e i am stuck again. Since i dont want to change storage rules to public.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this in your TableViewCell file

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
  myImageView.image = nil
}
```

Also, make sure that you set the empty image if your user doesn't have an image to load.